# I need to convert a slide left popout to a slide right popout with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having issues moving the slide out menu here from left to right. When I change all of the lefts to rights in the code it breaks. I also would like to know how hard it is to make the slide out menu push the main content and also a click anywhere else to close functionality would be nice too. I'm not sold on this code. It's just the best I have at the moment. If you know of something better or how to improve this I would love to see it.

https://jsfiddle.net/galnova/o79pt9bv/6/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
      <div class="sidebar-offcanvas">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
              <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </a>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>Navbar Left Example</h2>
            <p>This is an example to show the potential of an offcanvas layout pattern in Bootstrap. Try some responsive-range viewport sizes to see it in action.</p>
          </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
            </div><!--/span-->
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
            </div><!--/span-->
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
            </div><!--/span-->
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
            </div><!--/span-->
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
            </div><!--/span-->
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
            </div><!--/span-->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```